# Generate android apk using shell script from php?

Tags: php, android, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to generate Android `apk` files from shell script, I want to execute a shell script file from PHP. When I run the shell script in the terminal, it works perfectly. If I try to run the script using PHP, the shell script doesn't execute all the commands. The **ls** command in shell script works perfectly, but when executing using PHP, other commands doesn't work. I'm using xampp server in a Linux environment.

My shell script

```
cd /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/msvep4247-inghamautogroup-pulse-and/
./gradlew assembleDebug
cp -fr app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /opt/lampp/htdocs/sample/apk
ls
```

Shell script `ls` output

> app autolead_data_format.pdf build build.gradle cheek gradle
>   gradle.properties gradlew gradlew.bat lib local.properties
>   msvep4247-inghamautogroup-pulse-and.iml settings.gradle

My PHP script

```
   <?php
      echo shell_exec('ls');
      echo shell_exec('./generateApk.sh');
   ?>
```

PHP script `ls` output

> generateApk.sh generate.php APK

Note: `ls` outputs file names in the folder

I set all the file permissions for shell script in the xampp server. Can anyone describe where I'm mistaken? Awaiting responses...

Comment: 'Doesn't execute'... Any error?

Comment: Can you check if this works? `$output = shell_exec('./generateApk.sh');` `echo $output";`

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio already checked, but didn't work

Comment: Share your `ls -ls` output for both scripts

Comment: @modsfabio it executes the script, but not all commands

Comment: @Zumo de Vidrio will update question for ls outputs

Comment: The environment is different, when running 'through' php. Make sure to include/source all paths and such for the tools IN THE SCRIPT.

Comment: @TMS yes i've included the required script

Comment: @Keerthivasan Check if safe mode is disabled (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and make sure to enable all error reporting, then show us the error... (error_reporting(E_ALL))

Comment: @TMS okay, let me check and update the error if any

Comment: @Keerthivasan Also check this out - your apache (i presume) could have missing permissions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115054/php-shell-exec-permission-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: @TMS working, i just given full path. now it working perfectly.. post it as answer. i will accept your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142913/discussion-between-keerthivasan-and-tms).

Comment: @Keerthivasan sorry, but chat is not allowed in the office...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the full path to the script/executable, because the environment is different when running from php.

Comment: full path - shell_exec('/opt/lampp/htdocs/sample/generateApk.sh');

Comment: If you don't want to hard-code the path, you can use [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) - `dirname(__FILE__)`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `PATH` environment variable in PHP code that is executed in the web server is more limited than the one in the shell you're working in. But you can change environment variables in PHP, and the commands you start from it will see those changes.

```php
<?php
// set content type so the output is more readable in the browser
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
// set $PATH to some limited value
putenv('PATH=/bin:/sbin');
// verify, note that we have to use full path to 'env'
print(shell_exec("/usr/bin/env|grep '^PATH='"));
// this command won't run (assuming its full path is /usr/bin/id)
print(shell_exec("id"));
// add more directories to $PATH
putenv('PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin');
// verify again, we can use env without specifying the path this time
print(shell_exec("env|grep '^PATH='"));
// this command will
print(shell_exec("id"));
```

So you have to write `putenv('PATH=<your_shell_PATH_contents>');` at the top of your PHP script. Using full path to the shell script alone won't help if the script itself uses relative paths to binaries it starts.